# Animation disappears from front view but not the side view

Tags: animation

for some reason this animation that I am working on seems to disappear when viewed from the front but not from the side. I’m not sure why. I have provided screen recordings of it from both the side and front views so you can see what I am talking about. If someone could please help me fix this problem I would really appreciate it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like it has some keyframes on the X axis, the root bone or the armature as a whole object. Try looking at her from far away, or in a perspective view, it should become obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Josh, I tried zooming out from a different angle as you suggested but I still don't see why it keeps disappearing. I added another screen recording which now includes the timeline and dope sheet in case that helps anyone see what the problem is.

Comment: As you can see there is some movement of the whole character on the X axis.  You simply have to find out where are thoose movements programmed. I'm quite sure they are on the whole armature, in object mode, but it could be also on the root bone in pose mode. Go to Obiect mode, select the armature and delete any keyframe in the dopesheet. Then go to pose mode, select the root bone and delete any keyframe in the dopesheet.

Comment: Josh you are awesome. I went into the graph editor and could see the root bone was way out of place on the x axis from frame 1 to 20 and made the necessary adjustment. Now she doesn't disappear anymore. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the help.